# Finding asymptotic expansion of Modified Bessel function $I_{\nu}$ and $K_{\nu}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, bessel-functions

$$ \frac{I_1\left(\frac{2\sqrt{MN}}{N-1}\right)K_{0}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{M}}{N-1}\right)+I_0\left(\frac{2\sqrt{M}}{N-1}\right)K_{1}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{MN}}{N-1}\right)}{I_1\left(\frac{2\sqrt{MN}}{N-1}\right)K_{1}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{M}}{N-1}\right)-I_1\left(\frac{2\sqrt{M}}{N-1}\right)K_{1}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{MN}}{N-1}\right)}$$ becomes $coth{\sqrt{M}}$, as N approches to 1. I tried with large value approximations for $I_{\nu}$ and  $K_{\nu}$, But i am not getting $coth{\sqrt{M}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the leading term in the asymptotic expansions for $z\to\infty$,
\begin{align}
 I_j(z)&\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{e^z}{\sqrt{z}}\\
K_j(z)&\sim\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{e^{-z}}{\sqrt{z}}
\end{align}
for  $j=0,1$. Pre-factors of the functions are identical, the ratio is then
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\exp\left( 2\sqrt{M}\frac{\sqrt{N}-1}{N-1} \right)+\exp\left(- 2\sqrt{M}\frac{\sqrt{N}-1}{N-1} \right)}{\exp\left( 2\sqrt{M}\frac{\sqrt{N}-1}{N-1} \right)-\exp\left(- 2\sqrt{M}\frac{\sqrt{N}-1}{N-1} \right)}=\coth\frac{ 2\sqrt{M}}{\sqrt{N}+1} 
\end{equation} 
It approaches $\coth \sqrt{M}$ as $N\to 1$.

Comment: Thank you so much. @Paul Enta I was dividing the numerator and denominator by a zero valued term. and this caused problem. What a silly mistake.